# How can I groupby datetime data by month and create separate dataframes for each month

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am dealing with the following data:

```html
productSold          DateTime
    Car         2012-05-18 08:09:33
    AC          2012-05-23 05:09:33
   Table        2012-06-14 04:55:44
```

I want to group rows with month and create a new dataframe by month.

so, the output should be:

df1:

```html
 productSold          DateTime
        Car         2012-05-18 08:09:33
        AC          2012-05-23 05:09:33
```

df2:

```html
productSold          DateTime
       Table        2012-06-14 04:55:44
```

I am at the moment using the following code:

```py
#pf is the original data
pf.index = pd.to_datetime(pf['DateTime'])

a = pf.groupby(by=[pf.index.month, pf.index.year])
```

Please help me how can I achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt.to_period` to get the month, then `groupby`:

```
monthly = [d for k,d in df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.to_period('M'))]

print(month[0])
```

Output:

```
  productSold            DateTime
0         Car 2012-05-18 08:09:33
1          AC 2012-05-23 05:09:33
```